# how to call ASHX handler and getting the result back

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I have created a Handler which return integer value after doing some database work. i would like to know how can i get that value and assign that value to Label by calling that handler.

I have googled it and most of the example uses Jquery.AJAX calls to retrieve the value. I am sure i can also get the value by using that. BUT for some limitation in my company i am restricted to use code behind.

Any example will help.

```
Handler: http://somesite.com/Stores/GetOrderCount.ashx?sCode=VIC
which returns: 3
```

need to assign this to a label control

i have tried this much so far.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://somesite.com/Stores/GetOrderCount.ashx?sCode=VIC");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Label1.Text = response.ToString() // this does not work
```

Comment: what if you enter that URL into your browser, what do you got back? what's the format?

Comment: if i enter the URL in browser i get the value.. exactly what i expect to get... but i dont know how to get that in aspx page.

Comment: OKay,pls note that if you want to use HttpWebRequest, be careful with the response.Header, you may have to specify some header information in order to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [WebClient.DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
Label1.Text = client.DownloadString ("http://somesite.com/Stores/GetOrderCount.ashx?sCode=VIC");
```

You could also directly call your handler using ajax and update the label.

Here is a jQuery example:

```
$.get('Stores/GetOrderCount.ashx?sCode=VIC', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Comment: this gave me what i wanted... +1

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: I think your solution also works fine BUT it is much easier to use WebClient then stream